# Can I save flash game and play it without being connected to the Internet?

Tags: flash

Not sure if this question belongs on SO but ...

Can I play [Desktop Tower Defense](http://www.flashtowerdefence.com/flash/145/Desktop_Tower_Defense_1_9.html) without being connected to the Internet?

I can load the page and then disconnect from the net but my question is if I can download the game and play any time without connecting to the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer seems to be no, since he has made the .swf to not produce the game unless you go to his website... ie if it doesn't get a ping from some server if displays a nag screen...

Pretty pitiful in my opinion not to allow offline play for fans since he has earned a ton of money off the game (from 2007 onwards) but oh well... it might be that he is afraid of the misuse of the offline version on other websites, though he could have coded for that instead (it won't stop crackers and hackers of course)... I think he just wants to extort every penny out of the games since he has bothered to actually create a nice nag screen. (smileyface)

So the short answer seems to be no.